# Formating time field from excel file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I need to format the time value i get from an excel file to a string and then insert it into a sql table. I have used this code:

```
dtTruck = string.Format(dtTruck, "Long Time");
dtPlane = string.Format(dtPlane, "Long Time");
```

This worked only for the dtTruck field first time i executed the project. So this is not formating the value at all. It inserts the time value as a string into my sql table as this **0,29166666667** instead of this **07:00**

My code:

```
public void ReadExcelFile()
{
    string filename = @"C:\Temp\Copy2.xlsx";
    using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + filename + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\""))
    {
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            string sqlCmd1 = "SELECT  * FROM [Sheet1$]";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlCmd1, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                using (OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        alias = "" + reader[3];
                        codeT = "" + reader[4];
                        dtTruck = "" + reader[5];
                        codeP = "" + reader[6];
                        dtPlane = "" + reader[7];
                        dtDealer = "" + reader[8];

                        dtTruck = string.Format(dtTruck, "Long Time");
                        dtPlane = string.Format(dtPlane, "Long Time");

                        SearchForAdrIDAndCustID(Convert.ToString(reader[0]), Convert.ToString(reader[3]));
                        InsertData(custID, "" + reader[3], adrID, dtTruck, codeT, dtPlane, codeP, dtDealer);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ERROR in ReadExcelFile() method. Error Message : " + exception.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me with this ?

Comment: have you checked below lines, what output is coming



dtTruck = string.Format(dtTruck, "Long Time");
                        dtPlane = string.Format(dtPlane, "Long Time");

Comment: No matter what the output is 0,29166666667 if time is 07:00

Comment: How are the cells in your spreadsheet formatted? I've tested with `Time` and `Custom` and the data are retrieved just fine. You could also try putting it through `DateTime.TryParse` to see if that will yield any results.

Comment: The Fields are custom formatted to be **tt:mm** when i try string.Format nothing happens. But when i convert the data to **TimeSpan.FromDays** i get a correct output.

Comment: Do you mean **hh:mm** for the formatting? I've formatted my time cells like that and I can still retrieve the data without problem. There must be something different about the way your cells are formatted. What is the exact text being displayed in the cells and the exact text displayed in the formula bar when you click on the cell?

Answer (score 0):

did you try this :

```
dtTruck = string.Format(dtTruck,"{0:T}");
```

Reference :

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime